# In my Elastic Search upsert script, how do I refer to the upsert contents?

Tags: elasticsearch

The example upsert is:

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.counter += params.count",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "count" : 4
        }
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "counter" : 1
    }
}
```

Clearly, this can access the `_source` of the pre-existing document and modify it, and it can access the `params` to do that. But how would it access the `upsert` object submitted along side it? It does not appear to be in `ctx` as `upsert` nor `_upsert` and it's not the `doc`.

I would like to refer to it because I have a more involved document than the example, like 20+ fields, some nested parts with 5 fields each, and I don't think it's a great plan to put all the document details into both the `params` AND the `upsert` just so the script that pull it in.

Worst case I can write:

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
    "scripted_upsert": true,
    "script" : {
        "source": "if(ctx.op=="create"){ctx._source=params.upsert} else {ctx._source.counter += params.upsert.counter}",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "upsert" : {
               "counter" : 1
            }
        }
    },
    "upsert" : {}
}
```

But it's really … not great either.

Comment: Same problem here... how have you resolve it ?